# Using native libraries with JBOSS 4.2.0 on Linux

Tags: linux, jboss, pdflib

I am attempting to use pdflib 9 with JBOSS 4.2.0_GA09 on Ubuntu 10.04.  pdflib consists of a Java binding (pdflib.jar) and a native library (libpdflib_java.so).  I've installed libpdflib_java.so in $JBOSS_HOME/bin/native (which is equivalent to java.library.path shown below) and ran ldconfig on the directory.  I have also changed permissions to be 755.  The pdflib.jar file is included in my WAR file.

Despite this, I am getting the the following error:

```
013-07-09 09:46:18,334 ERROR [STDERR] Cannot load the PDFlib shared library/DLL for Java.
Make sure to properly install the native PDFlib library.

For your information, the current value of java.library.path is:
/home/<user>/Public/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/jboss-as/bin/native
2013-07-09 09:46:18,335 ERROR [STDERR] Jul 9, 2013 9:46:18 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no pdf_java in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1684)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:822)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:993)
    at com.pdflib.pdflib.<clinit>(pdflib.java:41)
    ...
```

What am I missing?  Are the files in the correct locations?  Is there a change I need to make to the configuration?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You installed `libpdflib_java.so` but it seems to look for `libpdf_java.so` instead. Maybe try to rename it?

Comment: Yikes, can't believe it was that easy.  I renamed the file, then found out that the set of files I received had a version mis-match (i.e. the jar file did not match the so file).  Somehow we managed to get the files mixed up.